# Stop screen from locking when laptop lid is closed

Tags: ubuntu, laptop, screensaver

In Ubuntu 12.04, how can I keep the screen from locking when I close my laptop?  I know I can disable locking altogether, but I do want the screen to lock when inactive.  And I want it to lock when I suspend.  I just don't want it to lock when I close the lid of the laptop.

Do I really have to be the person who sits in a meeting with their laptop lid **almost** closed?

Comment: Is this not a setting under "Power" in your System Settings?

Comment: You bring your laptop to meetings?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's the [workaround from Ubuntu 12.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/95295/how-to-prevent-screen-locking-when-lid-is-closed)

Check `/etc/acpi/lid.sh` and delete the lines that involve xscreensaver

There is a known [gnome powercfg bug in regard to this.](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-power-manager/+bug/1001908)

Specific status for this [bug #995840 for Ubuntu 12.04 and 12.10 is listed here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-power-manager/+bug/995840) under

"When laptop lid is closed screen locks even if it should not."

Current Status is "Confirmed" but the bug is "unassigned"

Comment: I think this must have worked at one point - I see where I commented out "/usr/share/acpi-support/screenblank" but my system is still blanking - still on 12.04.  There's a big section below that line that seems to relate to un-blanking when the lid is re-opened, which I didn't change and which doesn't seem to have any effect when I comment it.  Here's my complete lid.sh:
http://pastebin.com/XQPBxPsE

Comment: I'll check it out!

Comment: Is you system completely up to date?  Are you using Intel graphics? Do you always get the lock screen when you resume?  There was a similar bug reported here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xserver-xorg-video-intel/+bug/966744 that is finally resolved in regard to a hang on resume, but includes updates to lid.sh.